# Nested Json- How to acces items?

Tags: c#, json, string, parsing, object

I have a jsonString like this :

```
 {
"total": 0,
"subtotal": 88,
"page": 1,
"per_page": 100,
"search": "records",
"sort": {
    "by": null,
    "order": null
},
"results": {
    "x-name": {
        "records": "[{\"instance\":\"devsupport\",\"details\":[{\"id\":\"2\",\"hostname\":\"a\",\"ip\":\"i\",\"macaddr\":\"m\",\"user_created\":\"system\",\"date_created\":\"2015-07-10 11:45:20\",\"date_last_update\":null}]"
    },
    "y-name": {
        "records": "[{\"instance\":\"devsupport\",\"details\":[{\"id\":\"2\",\"hostname\":\"a\",\"ip\":\"i\",\"macaddr\":\"m\",\"user_created\":\"system\",\"date_created\":\"2015-07-10 11:45:20\",\"date_last_update\":null}]"
    }

  }
}
```

So my `jo object` is created like this and diplays correctly:

```
Object jo = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

My primary question is how can i get the `hostname,ip,macadd`r and so on and put them in a list considering the fact that
the records in "result" have all different names like `x-name, y-name` etc.

Comment: You will have to parse the value of `records` in `x-name`or `y-name` because it's a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your Json or parse the json inside `records` again, there is no other direct way like `object->results->xname->records->ip`

You can do like

```
recordsjson = object->results->xname->records
records = JObject.Parse(recordsjson);
ip = records->ip
```

Or

change your `records` structure like this one

```
"records": [
    {
      "instance": "devsupport",
      "details": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "hostname": "a",
          "ip": "i",
          "macaddr": "m",
          "user_created": "system",
          "date_created": "2015-07-10 11:45:20",
          "date_last_update": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```